# Android Google Maps + Place search result

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I have the following code to send a query to google about a particular location.

What i don't understand is, if i enter the following location on google maps (via browser)

"Grand Indonesia, Jakarta"

It returns the correct result.

However, using similar keywords on the code returns different result.

```
private String getPlacesUrl(String qry){

    try {
        qry = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(qry, "utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // place type to be searched
    String types = "types=geocode";

    // Country
    String country = "components=country:id";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = qry+"&"+types+"&"+sensor+"&"+mKey+"&"+country;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";
    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"+output+"?"+parameters;
    return url;
}
```

Does anyone knows why ? is there a better way to improve the accuracy?

Cheers...

Comment: Where can i get the mKey?? is that same as map key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying `types=geocode` while the results for [Grand Indonesia, Jakarta](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Grand+Indonesia%2C+Jakarta&data=!1m4!1m3!1d3734!2d106.8209663!3d-6.1942802!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x2e69f421c2ebd463%3A0xccfcc89b95aaf1ae!3m8!1m3!1d26081603!2d-95.677068!3d37.0625!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m2!3d-6.195167!4d106.820241) appear to be reflecting a business listing, not an address. If you remove the `types=geocode` you will receive the same result as the google maps results you received.